# Save Creation Date of File into Variable - BASH Script - UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, creation

In my bash script I am doing the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob 

for file in $LOCATION/EXF_TESTFORSTACKOVERFLOW_*.xml;
 do
touch "$file.FTC"
 done
```

But Before creating the .FTC File I would like to do an check:

IF creation Date of the xml File is more than 30 Minutes from sysdate - create FTC

IF its not older than 30 Minutes - do not create .FTC for this File.

Any suggestions how i can implement this check before doing the touch *"$file.FTC"*
I am not sure on how to check on the date for the files.
When using command *ls -l* I see that date i want to do this check on.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have a "create (or birth)" time -- it depends on what filesystem you have (check your /etc/fstab) -- you should probably use "mtime" instead, the last modified time, or "ctime", the last inode change (file rename, moved, etc)

Here's an example of the `stat` command to get time data for your files:

```sh
stat -c $'%n\nbirth\t%W = %w\naccess\t%X = %x\nmod\t%Y = %y\nchange\t%Z = %z\n' *
```

The output might look something like (this is an XFS file system):

```
file.txt
birth   0 = -
access  1595249263 = 2020-07-20 08:47:43.194000000 -0400
mod     1595249255 = 2020-07-20 08:47:35.453000000 -0400
change  1595249255 = 2020-07-20 08:47:35.453000000 -0400

test.dat
birth   0 = -
access  1595364240 = 2020-07-21 16:44:00.675000000 -0400
mod     1595364184 = 2020-07-21 16:43:04.786000000 -0400
change  1595364184 = 2020-07-21 16:43:04.786000000 -0400

menu.sh
birth   0 = -
access  1600025501 = 2020-09-13 15:31:41.977000000 -0400
mod     1600025496 = 2020-09-13 15:31:36.664000000 -0400
change  1600025496 = 2020-09-13 15:31:36.664000000 -0400
```

On my Mac with APFS, the birth time is a known value.

Comment: Thanks for you fast Answer. I am now trying this:
find $LOCATION -name $file -type f -mmin +30
But i am still getting files which are younger than 30 Minutes

Comment: This does not work, it also created the .FTC File for Files which is younger:

for file in $LOCATION/EXF_TESTFORSTACKOVERFLOW_*.xml;
 do
 
  find $LOCATION -name $file -type f -mmin +30
  
   touch "$file.FTC"
 done